# Restricting the number of checkboxes that can be selected to three excluding one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to restrict the number of checkboxes that can be selected to 3. The code below works but i would like level 6 and Level 7 to be always selectable i.e if some selects 1,2,3, then 6 and 7 should still be selectable.

HTML:

```
 <div class="pricing-levels-3">
      <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
      <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
    alert("allowed only 3");
}
})
```

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/ANNF9/)

Comment: What is the logic behind letting `6 and 7` always selectable? Is it always the last two checkboxes or more than 5th or what? If there is no specific logic, then just set a class to these checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, added a class to always selectble check boxes

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').not('.selectable').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
        alert("allowed only 3 main check boxes selectable");
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
          <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
          <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox selectable" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox  selectable" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better is to set some class to let elemnts selectable. That's said, this would work in your case, using jQuery [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
if ($('input[type=checkbox]:not(:gt(4)):checked').length < 3)
```

[-jsFiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/ANNF9/65/)

If this is alaways the last two you want selectable, use instead:

```
if ($('input[type=checkbox]:lt(-2):checked').length > 3)
```